# sencha touch / phonegap / iOS : German Strings for Next Done, Copy Paste....

Tags: internationalization, cordova, sencha-touch, copy-paste

I am using Sencha Touch with Phonegap to bring my app to iOS. When I use the keyboard to insert text or want to copy/paste some text I allways get the english Strings of 'Next', 'Done', 'Copy', 'Paste'...

How could I tell my app to use the german strings?

Thnx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a *de.lproj* directory (within the ressources folder of your project). Then create  with a file called *Localizable.strings* inside that folder. Finally add that directory to you project. That's it, you won't have to manually translate the strings (Done, Next, ...). It just should work...

Answer (score 0):

Complete process needed in my case:

- create cs.lproj directory with Localizable.strings inside
- copy it into XCode into project's Resources folder
- create cs.lproj inside project folder (**in Finder**)
- copy there InfoPlist.strings from en.lproj folder

only after that is the language correctly set in my case.